# Identify region of interest in image

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm currently trying to work on the challenge https://www.kaggle.com/c/noaa-right-whale-recognition; I've done basic image recognition work before (Identifying plankton), but this particular challenge requires an additional step: identifying where exactly the whale is in the given photograph, so as to bring the photo size down to a manageable chunk.

I've gone through and drawn rectangular annotations around the whales in the images; however, I'm not clear on how to proceed from here (or whether this was a useful step), and am new to the area, so I don't even have adequate knowledge of the proper terminology to do useful searches.

This appears to be what I gather is referred to as a segmentation problem, but that literature seems to be almost entirely unsupervised, and it's not clear how I would identify and extract the correct segment.  I would appreciate pointers to literature/tutorials in the area, especially ones that address:

1. Variable input image sizes
2. Utilizing existing supervised information.

Answer (score 3):

If the images are as clean as that one in the homepage, you can try a simple saliency detection algorithm [like this](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjzxounm6rJAhWBpJAKHblTAdoQFggnMAE&url=http://msr-waypoint.com/en-us/um/people/jiansun/papers/SalientDetection_CVPR07.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEV2VERnBskGclINhaRe0ABvVUfmQ&sig2=XwL4isDlCPO3lRyoDoW8rQ&bvm=bv.108194040,d.Y2I&cad=rja), whose [code can be found here](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Evicente/code.html). After detecting the saliency, you can write a simple program to draw a rectangle that comprises all the "important" (i.e. non-black) pixels found by the saliency algorithm.

If the images get more complicated, you can try the [Efficient Subwindow Search](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5166448) (ESS). It's a little bit more challenging but, if correctly used, it gives you the perfect rectangle automatically. [This paper used ESS for ROI detection](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5708154).

Both algorithms work for variable input sizes. As for using previous information, the first one doesn't use at all; the second one, depending on the implementation, will probably use.